# Is the Cartesian product of a circle and a point a circle?

Tags: general-topology

I’m trying to visualize what the set $S^1 \times\{(0,1)\}\cup\{(1,0)\}\times S^1$ looks like. How are the two circles positioned relative to each other?

Comment: Er... two circles?

Comment: Yep, just want to make sure.

Comment: Also, how are they positioned relative to each other?

Comment: As written, $(0,1)$ indicates the open interval. In order to express the product with a point, you should write $S^1 \times \{(0,1)\}$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens i’ll edit the question. Don’t know why the curly brackets disappeared.Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickStevens In that case, since $(1,0)$ is empty, we would have a finite cylinder.

Comment: You need backslashes before braces if you want them to show up.  Braces are used by MathJax to group items for processing, like multicharacter superscripts.  To get $x^{12}$ you type x^{12}, so if you want (for some reason) $x^{\{12\}}$ you need to type x^{\{12\}}

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I’m still fairly new to MathJax.

Comment: I am not sure how your question is related to your title.

Comment: For every topological space $X$ and every one-point-space $P$ we have $X\times P$ (and $P \times X$) homeomorphic to $X$.